# Missing mspdbcore.dll when compiling arm or arm64 programs with cl.exe from VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, arm, cl

My attempts to compile the simplest of C program to ARM, directly with cl.exe on a Win10 x86-64 environment always results in the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX64\arm\cl.exe" /c 1.c

1.c
c1: fatal error C1356: unable to find mspdbcore.dll
```

Note that everything works fine if I target x86 code: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c 1.c

I can compile and link this program just fine if doing it from within VS. Am I missing something on the PATH? It also seems that I only have two versions of mspdbcore.dll, one in Hostx64/x64 and another one in Hostx86/x86; nothing in the arm/arm64 equivalent folders.

File: 1.c:

```
int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned out the problem was connected to missing or incorrect environment variables after all...

I set up custom overrides for PATH, INCLUDE, LIB, and LIBPATH matching the values provided by the "VC++ Directories" options of a sample ARM VS project, and things are now compiling smoothly.

Edit #1: Settings I used, for VS2017: (They can be found in the "VC++ Directories" options widget I mentioned above)

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\arm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\ide;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Include\um
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\ARM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\lib\ARM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\lib\ARM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\arm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\arm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\arm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Lib\um\arm
set LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\atlmfc\lib\ARM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\ARM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, would you mind sharing your settings? Thanks!

Comment: Is it the same that the setvars scripts do in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\ ?

Answer (score 0):

Some VS directories have `mspdbcore.dll`, and some don't. Declaring the path in LIBPATH doesn't fix it.

For example, `.\bin\Hostx64\x64\` and `.\bin\Hostx86\x86\` have `mspdbcore.dll`, but `.\bin\Hostx64\x86\` does not, so if you want to run the 32-bit compiler on a 64-bit system, use `.\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe`, **not** `.\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe`.